# Using custom graph in import scenario throws "Cannot automate this screen. Error #103"

Tags: c#, acumatica

I'm trying to create an import scenario for a custom graph we built. The graph is a standard record entry graph for a DAC and some related tables.

I was able to create import scenarios for this graph before but now Acumatica shows an "Cannot automate this screen. Error #103" error beside the graph select combobox in the import scenario screen when I select this graph for automation.

I suppose something in the graph is the cause for this error, but I cannot find anything different from other graphs we are able to automate.

I haven't been able to find any references for this error in the documentation nor useful information from the trace screen.

Does anyone have any reference as to the meaning of this error? Is there a required attribute or member that should appear in a graph in order to automate it? Should I be looking for a specific Selector, Delegate or Attribute in the graph that might be causing this?

Here is the initial code of the graph:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PX.Data;
using PX.SM;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.IN;

namespace Syntegh.LeasingAddons
{
    using Descriptor;

    public class SYARAnnexEntry : PXGraph<SYARAnnexEntry, SYARAnnex> //, PXImportAttribute.IPXPrepareItems
    {
        const string AnnexPrefix = "AP";

        public PXSetup<SYARAnnexSetup> AnnexSetup;

        public PXSelect<SYARAnnex> Annexes;

        [PXViewName(Descriptor.Messages.AnnexItems)]
        public PXSelect<SYARAnnexItem,
                Where<SYARAnnexItem.annexID, Equal<Current<SYARAnnex.annexID>>>,
                OrderBy<Asc<SYARAnnexItem.itemNbr>>> AnnexItems;

        [PXViewName(Descriptor.Messages.Invoices)]
        public PXSelectReadonly2<ARInvoice,
            InnerJoin<ARTran,
                On<ARTran.refNbr, Equal<ARInvoice.refNbr>>>,
            Where<SYARTranExtension.annexID, Like<Current<SYARAnnex.annexID>>>,
            OrderBy<Desc<ARInvoice.docDate,
                Desc<ARInvoice.refNbr>>>> Invoices;

        public PXSelectReadonly<SYARPlannedPayment,
                    Where<SYARPlannedPayment.annexID, Equal<Current<SYARAnnex.annexID>>>,
                    OrderBy<Asc<SYARPlannedPayment.itemNbr,
                        Asc<SYARPlannedPayment.period>>>> PlannedPayments;

        public PXSelect<UploadFile> Files;

        public SYARAnnexEntry() : base()
        {
            SYARAnnexSetup Setup = AnnexSetup.Current;

            action.MenuAutoOpen = true;
            action.AddMenuAction(viewConfiguration);
            action.AddMenuAction(openAnnex);
            action.AddMenuAction(changeAP);
            action.AddMenuAction(cancelAnnex);
            changeAP.SetCaption(PXMessages.Localize(Descriptor.Messages.ChangeID));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what version of acumatica do you use?

Comment: Do you map your screen based on this graph in sitemap?

Comment: I got this issue before,.in that case the problem i found was that, i had two grid controls  in the page using the same datamember [One was hidden from the UI]. After deleting one of the grid, this issue was resolved.

Comment: @Kirill This is running on version 5.30.2562
Yes, the error pops beside the dropdown when I select the view from the sitemap.
I have 3 grid controls but with three different DataMembers, one for detail (AnnexItems select) and two for related records (Invoices and PlannedPayments).